# Matching a substring between two special characters EXCLUDING the characters

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

So I want to capture the sub-string between two special characters in JavaScript, using regular expressions.
Say I have the string `"$Hello$, my name is $John$"`, I would want .match to return the array of `[Hello, John]`. 
*In addition, I do not want to capture the match between two matches. So I wouldn't want to capture $, my name is $, since it is technically between two '$'s.

The regular expression I have used is

```
var test = str.match(/(?<=\$)(.*)(?=\$)/);
```

Which works, but duplicates each entry twice. So it has
[Hello, Hello, John, John]. 
I have also used `var test = str.match(/(?<=\$)[^\$]+?(?=\$)/g)`
But this returns everything inbetween each match (the example i listed above $, my name is $.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Be aware that lookbehinds are [not yet well-supported](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind).

Comment: `"$Hello$, my name is $John$".split("$").filter((el, i ) => i % 2)` outputs `["Hello", "John"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the first and the second dollar sign and use a capturing group to capture char is in between using a negated character class matching any char except a dollar sign.

```
\$([^$]+)\$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YN8xu1/1)

Instead of using match, you could use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). For example:

```js
var str = "$Hello$, my name is $John$";
var regex = /\$([^$]+)\$/g;
var m;
var test = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  test.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the desired matches with `/(?<=\$)[^$ ]+(?=\$)/g`.

It will match every word between two dollar signs, but it relies on two assumptions. The first is that `$` can't appear as a character in the sentence, e.g. `$Your$ total is $4.50, cash or $card$`. The second is that there will never be a space inside the dollar signs, e.g. `$Hello$, my name is $John Smith$`. As long as that works, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve it without employing lookbehinds:

`(?:.*?\$(.*?)\$) /g`

All I am doing is lazily looking for a `$`, and then capturing everything lazily until the next `$` is encountered. This is repeated several times via the `/g` flag. Each capturing group will then have the desired string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeQgMa/2)